# How to export files saved using the FileSystemStorage apis

Tags: local-storage, codenameone

Files created by FileSystemStorage are well hidden.  How would you recommend making them interoperable with the outside world?

Answer (score 0):

Apps are isolated from one another on devices, historically there were some ways around it (SDCard) but those are not as common even on Android. You can use the SDCard to store a file for Android and it will be visible and replaceable when plugging in the device.

iOS has the `ios.fileSharingEnabled` but it is relatively unintuitive as you have to connect the app via itunes to upload/delete files into the device.

I would use something like a https://www.codenameone.com/blog/native-file-open-dialogs.html[file picker] or the [Dropbox integration](https://github.com/chen-fishbein/dropbox-codenameone-sdk/) to let users pick a file. To extract a file from the app I'd just use the share operation in `Display`.

Comment: I know this isn't the appropriate place for a tutorial on IOS, but there must be some API for shared documents, like pictures for example that can be manipulated by many different apps.

Comment: Not manipulated. We have a gallery API and quite a few other API's but you are being very vague about what you are actually trying to accomplish. There is no "generic" API but there are use case specific solutions.

Comment: I'm adding a capability to save/edit/view games, similar to what is already available on the PC version; but a key part of any file sandbox is to get the files OUT of the sandbox to be shared.  On real computers, the files are readily available to all the other programs. Not so on IOS.

Comment: The "right" solution in the age of the cloud is to have the saved games in the cloud in a shared space so you can pick up a saved game on the PC even if you saved it in your Android phone or iPad. This sort of usage isn't supported, phones don't have a file system explorer in the traditional sense we have on PC's/Macs

Comment: They do, its just hidden and protected from non jailbroken devices.  I agree we're not going to get Apple to change their public file ecosystem, so how can i use codenameone to read/write icloud acessible files.

Comment: Check out the file open dialog link from Steve I linked above. He uses icloud